# How to use a contributed C++ wxwidget in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I wrote a small application in wxpython which among other things shows candlestick OHLC plots using matplotlib. However I wanted to increase the perfomance of the charting using instead a compiled C++ component. There is one available for wxwidgets: [freechart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/freechart/) which basically does what I want.

Is there a (simple) way to add bindings in a way compatible with wxpython?

It is not necessary for me to make it very complete and cover all options/classes/methods - I'd rather want to be able to use just a very small subset.

I do not want to go the C++ route all the way since I want to reuse the python code that I have and use scripting...

I would be grateful for any pointers to some tutorials/docs on the web. I did not find any so far..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching on the wxPython-users group and also crucial direct help on that list from Robin Dunn (deleting a destructor in the SWIG interface file) I managed to get a working C++ extension (for the current wxPython 2.9.4) for the example C++ class FooButton which was used in the [tutorial on wiki.wxpython.org](http://wiki.wxpython.org/C++Extensions)

Since it may be useful for someone who would stumble on this question (and for me it was rather nontrivial to get it working) I am posting the code below.

The C++ header file `foobutton.h` is

```
class FooButton : public wxButton
{
public:
    FooButton(wxWindow *parent,
              wxWindowID id,
              const wxString& label,
              const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
              const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
              long style = 0,
              const wxValidator& validator = wxDefaultValidator,
              const wxString& name = "foobutton");
    ~FooButton();
private:
    DECLARE_CLASS(FooButton);
};
```

The implementation `foobutton.cpp` is

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "foobutton.h"

IMPLEMENT_CLASS(FooButton, wxButton);

FooButton::FooButton(wxWindow *parent,
          wxWindowID id,
          const wxString& label,
          const wxPoint& pos,
          const wxSize& size,
          long style,
          const wxValidator& validator,
          const wxString& name)
    : wxButton(parent, id, label, pos, size, style, validator, name)
{
    SetLabel("foo");
}

FooButton::~FooButton()
{

};
```

The SWIG interface file `foobutton.i` is

```
%module foobutton

%{
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/wxPython/wxPython.h"
#include "wx/wxPython/pyclasses.h"
class wxPyTreeCtrl;

#include "foobutton.h"
%}

class wxPyTreeCtrl;

%import typemaps.i
%import my_typemaps.i

%import core.i
%import controls.i

%pythoncode { import wx }
%pythoncode { __docfilter__ = wx._core.__DocFilter(globals()) }

class FooButton : public wxButton
{
public:
    FooButton(wxWindow *parent,
              wxWindowID id,
              const wxString& label,
              const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
              const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
              long style = 0,
              const wxValidator& validator = wxDefaultValidator,
              const wxString& name = "foobutton");
//    ~FooButton(); COMMENTING OUT THE DESTRUCTOR IS IMPORTANT !
private:
    DECLARE_CLASS(FooButton);
};
```

Some comments: the declaration `class wxPyTreeCtrl;` was necessary as it seems to be missing in `pyclasses.h`. Also it was very important to erase the C++ destructor from the SWIG interface as then the FooButton object was promptly garbage collected and the FooButton did not show up in the application (thanks to Robin Dunn!).

I used swig 1.3.29 with the applied patch from the wxPython distribution.

Since it was also not completely trivial to build the extension, I list below the contents of the `Makefile`:

```
WX_CXXFLAGS = -fpic  `wx-config --cxxflags` -I/home/romuald/software/wxPython-src-2.9.4.0/wxPython/include -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table
WX_LIBS = `wx-config --libs` -lwxcode_gtk2u_freechart-2.9
LIBS =

py: foobutton.o foobutton_wrap.o
    g++ -shared foobutton.o foobutton_wrap.o $(WX_LIBS) $(LIBS) -o _foobutton.so

foobutton.o: foobutton.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $(WX_CXXFLAGS) foobutton.cpp

foobutton_wrap.o: foobutton_wrap.cxx
    g++ -c $(WX_CXXFLAGS) -I/usr/include/python2.7 foobutton_wrap.cxx 

foobutton_wrap.cxx: foobutton.i
    wxswig -c++ -python -Wall -nodefault -python -keyword -new_repr -modern -D__WXGTK__ -I/home/romuald/software/wxPython-src-2.9.4.0/wxPython/src foobutton.i
```

Note the `-fpic` and `-DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table` options in the C++ compiler flags. With the above the extension compiles and the FooButton shows up in a wxPython application. There is a warning message about the missing destructor but everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way that I'm aware of. You would probably have to learn SWIG for the wxPython 2.8 series and early 2.9 or SIP for the wxPython Phoenix project to make it work properly. However, for charting purposes, you might want to take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) which can be integrated with wxPython already.

Comment: The only other alternative would be to write some minimal high-level C++ wrappers (or even `extern "C"` wrapper), and write trivial bindings for those. Then you can treat your chart widgets as generic opaque widgets, and call the wrappers to do the non-generic stuff. That's _occasionally_ worth doing, but usually you're better off just SWIGging the library.

Comment: @abarnet and Mike Driscoll: thanks! Is there some place where the use of SWIG in the context of wxPython is described with some example? I found various comments that one has to use a specially patched version of SWIG for wxpython and also a tutorial [link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/C%2B%2BExtensions) which however has some comments at the end that it uses several constructs which are out of date...

Comment: In fact I was using matplotlib - but wanted to switch to a C++ solution for candlestick charting (freechart) for perfomance reasons.. (and also that particular kind of plot looks nicer)

Comment: You'd probably need to look at one of the wxPython build pages: http://www.wxpython.org/builddoc.php for 2.9 or http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html for 2.8. Or you could ask on the wxPython mailing list where the core devs are.